# Perl regex: how to know number of matches

Tags: regex, perl, extract

I'm looping through a series of regexes and matching it against lines in a file, like this:

```
for my $regex (@{$regexs_ref}) {
    LINE: for (@rawfile) {
        /@$regex/ && do {
            # do something here
            next LINE;
        };
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to know how many matches I've got (so I can process it accordingly..)?

If not maybe this is the wrong approach..? Of course, instead of looping through every regex, I could just write one recipe for each regex. But I don't know what's the best practice?

Comment: What do you mean by how many matches you've got? The number of times a particular pattern has matched across the file? Some subpattern within a given expression? What do you mean by processing it accordingly? Our suggestions will be more helpful to you if you provide more context.

Comment: Basically I'm asking if this could have been written better? The only change is that I now have the regexes in a database.

http://code.google.com/p/codalyzer/source/browse/trunk/parser/Parser.pm

Comment: Have you read [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) (specifically the sections on `s///` and `m//`)?

Comment: @Ether, yeah, why do you ask?

Comment: @Karl: because the answer is in there. :)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? =)

Comment: Think I know what you mean now.. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do your matching in list context (i.e., basically assigning to a list), you get all of your matches and groupings in a list. Then you can just use that list in scalar context to get the number of matches.

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Example:

```
my @list = /$my_regex/g;
if (@list)
{
  # do stuff
  print "Number of matches: " . scalar @list . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, perhaps what I'm looking for. @list now contains every match (i.ex $1, $2, $3..) or..?

Comment: Yup, `@list` has all the matches. (And of course, the size of the list is the number of matches!) Really, if you're going to do something with every capture/match, it's smartest to just iterate with `foreach` over that match list, kind of like how the C-style `for` is discouraged in Perl. :-)

Comment: Excellent. Can I use my array_ref as a @list? Can you show me an example? Yes I'm going to do something with every capture/match, just as in http://code.google.com/p/codalyzer/source/browse/trunk/parser/Parser.pm

Comment: ..only now I store all regexes in a database, and was looking for the "best practice"-way to do it. :-)

Comment: @Karl S Haugen: Can you please clarify what you mean? (I don't see an `array_ref` in the code above)

Comment: I was thinking something like this:
    my @hits;
    for my $regex (@{$regexs_ref}) {
        LINE: for (@rawfile) {
            @hits = ($_ =~ /@$regex/);
        }
    }

Of course I can change for to foreach :-). Is this what you were thinking?

Comment: Perhaps I need to re-think this. Maybe just having each regex explicitly typed is the best way..? Like a do in the link above. Basically what I want to do: parse a log file, do something with the matches, and then insert accordingly into a database. Best solution??

Comment: Yeah, that should basically work. I understand the `@{$regexs_ref}` part, but why do you have `/@$regex/` as your match pattern? Are you looking to match a literal `@` character before your regex? If so, you might want to escape the `@` sign, otherwise Perl might interpret that as an array dereference. (You don't need the brackets for a simple reference scalar, so Perl could get confused in the regex)

Comment: Isn't that the dereferenced array ref I get from fetchall_arrayref()?

I have like my $regexs_ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612756/perl-best-practices-file-parser-using-regexes-and-database-storage

Comment: Yeah, I get the array reference part (for `$regexs_ref`. That's fine. It's the `/@$regex/` that I don't get. A regex pattern is a string, and therefore should be scalar. Basically, since you're doing two dereference steps, it feels like you are expecting `$regexs_ref` to carry a list of <b>more list references</b>, which in turn refer to lists. In reality you just have a reference to one list of regular expression patterns, if I'm understanding this correctly. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep track of that yourself.  Here is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @regexes = (
    qr/b/,
    qr/a/,
    qr/foo/,
    qr/quux/,
);

my %matches = map { $_ => 0 } @regexes;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    for my $regex (@regexes) {
        next unless $line =~ /$regex/;
        $matches{$regex}++;
    }
}

for my $regex (@regexes) {
    print "$regex matched $matches{$regex} times\n";
}

__DATA__
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score 2):

In [CA::Parser](http://code.google.com/p/codalyzer/source/browse/trunk/parser/Parser.pm)'s processing associated with matches for `/$CA::Regex::Parser{Kills}{all}/`, you're using captures `$1` all the way through `$10`, and most of the rest use fewer. If by the number of matches you mean the number of captures (the highest *n* for which `$n` has a value), you could use Perl's special `@-` array (emphasis added):

> #### @LAST_MATCH_START
>
> #### @-
>
> `$-[0]` is the offset of the start of the last successful match. `$-[n]` is the offset of the start of the substring matched by *n*-th subpattern, or `undef` if the subpattern did not match.
>   Thus after a match against `$_`, `$&` coincides with `substr $_, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0]`. Similarly, `$n` coincides with
>
> ```
> substr $_, $-[n], $+[n] - $-[n]
> ```
>
> if `$-[n]` is defined, and `$+` coincides with
>
> ```
> substr $_, $-[$#-], $+[$#-] - $-[$#-]
> ```
>
> **One can use `$#-` to find the last matched subgroup in the last successful match.** Contrast with `$#+`, the number of subgroups in the regular expression. Compare with `@+`.
>
> This array holds the offsets of the beginnings of the last successful submatches in the currently active dynamic scope. `$-[0]` is the offset into the string of the beginning of the entire match. The *n*-th element of this array holds the offset of the nth submatch, so `$-[1]` is the offset where `$1` begins, `$-[2]` the offset where `$2` begins, and so on.
>
> After a match against some variable `$var`:
>
> - $` is the same as `substr($var, 0, $-[0])`
> - `$&` is the same as `substr($var, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0])`
> - `$'` is the same as `substr($var, $+[0])`
> - `$1` is the same as `substr($var, $-[1], $+[1] - $-[1])`
> - `$2` is the same as `substr($var, $-[2], $+[2] - $-[2])`
> - `$3` is the same as `substr($var, $-[3], $+[3] - $-[3])`

Example usage:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @patterns = (
  qr/(foo(bar(baz)))/,
  qr/(quux)/,
);

chomp(my @rawfile = <DATA>);

foreach my $pattern (@patterns) {
  LINE: for (@rawfile) {
    /$pattern/ && do {
      my $captures = $#-;
      my $s = $captures == 1 ? "" : "s";
      print "$_: got $captures capture$s\n"; 
    };
  }
}

__DATA__
quux quux quux
foobarbaz
```

Output:

```
foobarbaz: got 3 captures
quux quux quux: got 1 capture
```

Answer (score 2):

How about below code:

```
my $string = "12345yx67hjui89";    
my $count = () = $string =~ /\d/g;
print "$count\n";
```

It prints 9 here as expected.

Comment: It is nothing but merging typical two lines into one.
You can do the same with two lines.

 my @count = $string =~ /\d/g;
 print scalar @count;

So, why to store the matched values in an array if it is not required, instead just use an empty list and assign it to a scalar. It will do.