# In regular expression matching of Perl, is it possible to know number of matches in a{n,}?

Tags: regex, perl, match

What I mean is:

For example, `a{3,}` will match 'a' at least three times greedly. It may find five times, 10 times, etc. I need this number. I need this number for the rest of the code.

I can do the rest less efficiently without knowing it, but I thought maybe Perl has some built-in variable to give this number or is there some trick to get it?

Comment: I'm not a Perl user but could you not capture it, assign to a variable and then find the length of it? Seems simple enough to me

Comment: Are you asking the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610295/perl-regex-how-to-know-number-of-matches?

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. Perhaps you should ask about the reason you need this length.

Comment: thanks for your comments all, it seems like i will actually assign it to a variable and then i will compare lengths but i thought while perl already knows it, code may be faster. reason i want it is that pattern i seek for has several {n,} matches for different parts of it. firstly i want to find some equal ones, then it will be a little more complicated

Answer (score 2):

Use [@LAST_MATCH_END and @LAST_MATCH_START](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
my $str = 'jlkjmkaaaaaamlmk';
$str =~ /a{3,}/;
say $+[0]-$-[0];
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

**NB: This will work only with a one-character pattern.**

Answer (score 2):

Just capture it and use `length`.

```
if (/(a{3,})/) {
   print length($1), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pattern of type `/AB{n,}/` where *A* and *B* are complex patterns, we can split the regex into multiple pieces:

```
my $string = "ABABBBB";
my $n = 3;

my $count = 0;
TRY:
while ($string =~ /A/gc) {
  my $pos = pos $string; # remember position for manual backtracking
  $count++ while $string =~ /\GB/g;
  if ($count < $n) {
    $count = 0;
    pos($string) = $pos; # restore previous position
  } else {
    last TRY;
  }
}
say $count;
```

Output: `4`

However, embedding code into the regex to do the counting may be more desirable, as it is more general:

```
my $string = "ABABBBB";
my $count;
$string =~ /A(?{ $count = 0 })(?:B(?{ $count++ })){3,}/ and say $count;
```

Output: `4`.

The downside is that this code won't run on older perls. (Code was tested on v14 & v16).

---

**Edit:** The first solution will fail if the `B` pattern backtracks, e.g. `$B = qr/BB?/`. That pattern should match the `ABABBBB` string three times, but the strategy will only let it match two times. The solution using embedded code allows proper backtracking.

Comment: thank you i will play with it and try to adapt to my need, thanks again for giving me idea to split regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea (maybe this is what you already had?) assuming the pattern you're interested in counting has multiple characters and variable length:

- capture the substring which matches the `pattern{3,}` subpattern
- then match the captured substring globally against `pattern` (note the absence of the quantifier), and force a list context on `=~` to get the number of matches.

Here's a sample code to illustrate this (where `$patt` is the subpattern you're interested in counting)

```
my $str = "some catbratmatrattatblat thing";
my $patt = qr/b?.at/; 

if ($str =~ /some ((?:$patt){3,}) thing/) {
    my $count = () = $1 =~ /$patt/g;
    print $count;
    ...
}
```

---

Another (admittedly somewhat trivial) example with 2 subpatterns

```
my $str = "some catbratmatrattatblat thing 11,33,446,70900,";
my $patt1 = qr/b?.at/; 
my $patt2 = qr/\d+,/;

if ($str =~ /some ((?:$patt1){3,}) thing ((?:$patt2){2,})/) {
    my ($substr1, $substr2) = ($1, $2);
    my $count1 = () = $substr1 =~ /$patt1/g;
    my $count2 = () = $substr2 =~ /$patt2/g;
    say "count1: " . $count1;
    say "count2: " . $count2;
}
```

---

## Limitation(s) of this approach:

Fails miserably with lookarounds. See [amon's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316858/in-regular-expression-matching-of-perl-is-it-possible-to-know-number-of-matches#comment25118752_17317990).

Comment: Lookarounds can make this strategy fail: `$str = "A,B,B,B,C"; $patt = qr/(?<=,)B,/;`. The regex: `/A,($patt{3,})C/`. Output: `2`. Btw, capture groups inside `$patt` won't affect the outcome.

Comment: @amon, Thanks, I shall make a note of it.